# How do I embed an image from the web into a Trello card comment or description?

Tags: trello, images, url, embed

So far I have been successful embedding Youtube videos into Trello card comments; simply by including the URL in the comment Trello picks it up and renders an embedded Youtube thumbnail.

What I would like to do is the same thing, but with a simple PNG image. I don't want to upload the image as it is a Balsamiq mockup permalink which will get updated periodically, and I want the latest version to be displayed on the Trello card.

However, pasting the image URL into the Trello card has no effect.

Am I missing somthing?

Answer (score 18):

I don't think you can do this in the comments, but you can do this in the Description using the Markdown style:

```
![Alt text](http://url/image.png "Optional title")
```

For more info on the markdown syntax, check out: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img

Comment: This is right, you can't do this in the comments. It parses it as a link.

Comment: @user73239 true... I was kind of hoping that in 6 years since this answer was posted, images in comments would now be supported. Unfortunately this is not the case yet (2018-11-25).

Comment: You don't need the `!`. If I write it then it is getting rendered.

Comment: It's not working anymore :(

Answer (score 15):

Further to the other answers: within the Description, you can also embed images that have been added as attachments to the card. (Note: this will *only* work in the description, and not in comments.)

1. Right-click on the attachment image and select "Copy Link Address"
2. In the Description, enter the following:

   ```
   ![](link address goes here)
   ```

e.g.

```
![](https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/55c1647...b6b/myimage.png)
```

Comment: Can we please request this as a feature somwehere?

Answer (score 8):

Card comments use embed.ly to display content inline, so a link to a Twitter status or YouTube video will embed the status or video. Here is a full list of providers: http://embed.ly/providers. Trello only display services that offer SSL, though. And it won't work for any image URL, just those in the list of providers. If you upload images as attachments, it will show a preview in the activity feed.